# Use data from Javascript callback in Rails App

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using a (3rd party) JS `User List` in my Rails app. When a `User` is clicked, there is a JS callback --

```
function onUserSelected(userId) {
    ...
}
```

When this happens, I want to load the `User Profile` page, which shows info for that `User` --

```
<%= link_to 'User Profile', user_id(@userId) %>
```

I understand that JS is client side, but what would be the best way to tell my rails app to load the `User Profile` page for that `User`?

Comment: Could you provide a link to the "User List" library you're using. What does userData contain?

Comment: I can't link to it unfortunately. For the sake of this question, userData could just be a userId string that the Profile page can use to fetch user info (edited)

Comment: So you basically want to load parts of the page via AJAX. Did you try anything?